# Renaming attachment files to the post title it's being added to in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

Like the title says, I am trying to rename media gallery uploads to the title of the initial post the file is being added to.

I found the following function and modified it to change the filename to the file's author slug

```
// file renamer (used for EDL images)
function file_renamer( $filename ) {
  $info = pathinfo( $filename );
  $ext  = empty( $info['extension'] ) ? '' : '.' . $info['extension'];
  $name = basename( $filename, $ext );
  global $current_user;
  get_currentuserinfo();

  return   $current_user->user_login . $ext;
}
```

However- that wasn't good enough for the client. I haven't found any solutions to this yet online. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Edit - Just want to add that I am using advanced custom fields for this as well. Here is the rest of the code for this process, which directs specific custom field images to a certain directory-

```
// EDL uploaded images will go to the /edl directory in uploads for these fields.
add_filter('acf/upload_prefilter/name=edl_dealer_logo', 'field_name_upload_prefilter');
add_filter('acf/upload_prefilter/name=edl_image', 'field_name_upload_prefilter');
add_filter('acf/upload_prefilter/name=edl_gallery_image', 'field_name_upload_prefilter');

function field_name_upload_prefilter($file) {
// in this filter we add a WP filter that alters the upload path
add_filter( 'sanitize_file_name', 'file_renamer', 10 );
add_filter('upload_dir', 'field_name_upload_dir');
return $file;
}
// second filter
  function field_name_upload_dir($uploads) {

  $mydir = '/edl';
  // here is where we later the path
  $uploads['path'] = $uploads['basedir'].$mydir;
  $uploads['url'] = $uploads['baseurl'].$mydir;

  $uploads['subdir'] = '/edl';
  return $uploads;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you might be able look at `$_POST["post_ID"]`, use WP's `get_post()` and then if a post has been found, call get `$post->post_title` for the filename.

Or does ACF upload those asynchronously via Ajax? In any case, the post ID should be transmitted when uploading I believe, but you might have to look at your browser's developer tools to find out what the field name is.

The following works in my install. Be advised that this would run for all file uploads, so you might want to add some precautions.

```
function file_renamer( $filename ) {
    $info = pathinfo( $filename );
    $ext  = empty( $info['extension'] ) ? '' : '.' . $info['extension'];
    $name = basename( $filename, $ext );
    if( $post_id = array_key_exists("post_id", $_POST) ? $_POST["post_id"] : null) {
        if($post = get_post($post_id)) {
            return $post->post_title . $ext;
        }
    }
    get_currentuserinfo();

    return   $current_user->user_login . $ext;
  }
add_filter( 'sanitize_file_name', 'file_renamer', 10, 1 );
```

Comment: I appreciate the response janh2! However I am unable to get any post info inside the renaming function. I believe they are uploaded using the standard wordpress media gallery functionality. I am seeing a callback after the image uploads which includes "uploadedToTitle":"Summer Haven", but am not sure how to implement this as it is obviously being passed after the image is already uploaded.

Comment: I've just tested it with the general media upload feature, triggered from the editor. In the ajax-request, it adds `data[wp-refresh-post-lock][post_id]=12345` (=ID of post it belongs to) in the POST request. Maybe you could use that?

Comment: You're right, I am seeing it too. I tried the following though and nothing is showing up. Thank you for your help though.                                  
    function file_renamer( $filename ) {
      $info = pathinfo( $filename );
      $ext  = empty( $info['extension'] ) ? '' : '.' . $info['extension'];
      $name = basename( $filename, $ext );

      return $_POST["post_ID"] . $ext;
  }

Comment: That would have to be $_POST["wp-refresh-post-lock"]["post_id"], I believe. Does it work with using that instead of $_POST["post_ID"]?

Comment: Still nothing, unfortunately.

Comment: I've edited my original answer with a function that works for me.
I had looked at the wrong requests before, apparently. `$_POST["post_id"]` is correct.
Let me know if that works for you as well. And you might want to add more sanitizing on the filename, not just return the title as I did in this demo

Comment: hello janh ,I did not find a function for direct message I use your code it works well but I have a slight problem, look here [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64811111/snippet-rename-the-images-in-wordpress-after-upload)