# Wordpress rename uploaded images based on the post_title

Tags: php, wordpress, function, file-upload, elementor

I'm looking for a way to tell wordpress to rename the images attached to the post, by the name of the post.

I found this [plugin](https://fr.wordpress.org/plugins/media-file-renamer/) to do the trick but.. it's stupid to use a plugin for such a simple function. . So I found this code in this [article](https://brutalbusiness.com/automatically-set-the-wordpress-image-title-alt-text-other-meta/)

```
/* Automatically set the image Title, Alt-Text, Caption & Description upon upload
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
add_action( 'add_attachment', 'my_set_image_meta_upon_image_upload' );
function my_set_image_meta_upon_image_upload( $post_ID ) {

    // Check if uploaded file is an image, else do nothing

    if ( wp_attachment_is_image( $post_ID ) ) {

        $my_image_title = get_post( $post_ID )->post_title;

        // Sanitize the title:  remove hyphens, underscores & extra spaces:
        $my_image_title = preg_replace( '%\s*[-_\s]+\s*%', ' ',  $my_image_title );

        // Sanitize the title:  capitalize first letter of every word (other letters lower case):
        $my_image_title = ucwords( strtolower( $my_image_title ) );

        // Create an array with the image meta (Title, Caption, Description) to be updated
        // Note:  comment out the Excerpt/Caption or Content/Description lines if not needed
        $my_image_meta = array(
            'ID'        => $post_ID,            // Specify the image (ID) to be updated
            'post_title'    => $my_image_title,     // Set image Title to sanitized title
            'post_excerpt'  => $my_image_title,     // Set image Caption (Excerpt) to sanitized title
            'post_content'  => $my_image_title,     // Set image Description (Content) to sanitized title
        );

        // Set the image Alt-Text
        update_post_meta( $post_ID, '_wp_attachment_image_alt', $my_image_title );

        // Set the image meta (e.g. Title, Excerpt, Content)
        wp_update_post( $my_image_meta );

    } 
}
```

and another one [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46551211/renaming-attachment-files-to-the-post-title-its-being-added-to-in-wordpress)

```
function file_renamer( $filename ) {
    $info = pathinfo( $filename );
    $ext  = empty( $info['extension'] ) ? '' : '.' . $info['extension'];
    $name = basename( $filename, $ext );
    if( $post_id = array_key_exists("post_id", $_POST) ? $_POST["post_id"] : null) {
        if($post = get_post($post_id)) {
            return $post->post_title . $ext;
        }
    }
    get_currentuserinfo();

    return   $current_user->user_login . $ext;
  }
add_filter( 'sanitize_file_name', 'file_renamer', 10, 1 );
```

both work but how do you combine them into one code?

what is the best way to deal with this problem without using a plugin?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This code works with post types (posts, pages, products). Change filename and ads alt, title, caption and description meta to image.

But when its about attributes, categories keeps the filename and add it to alt, title, etc.

```
function file_renamer( $filename ) {
    $info = pathinfo( $filename );
    $ext  = empty( $info['extension'] ) ? '' : '.' . $info['extension'];
    $name = basename( $filename, $ext );


    if( $post_id = array_key_exists("post_id", $_POST) ? $_POST["post_id"] : null) {
        if($post = get_post($post_id)) {
            return $post->post_title . $ext;
        }
    }
    
    $my_image_title = $post;
    

    $file['name'] = $my_image_title  . - uniqid() . $ext; // uniqid method
    // $file['name'] = md5($name) . $ext; // md5 method
    // $file['name'] = base64_encode($name) . $ext; // base64 method

    return $filename;


  }
add_filter( 'sanitize_file_name', 'file_renamer', 10, 1 );

/* Automatically set the image Title, Alt-Text, Caption & Description upon upload
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
add_action( 'add_attachment', 'my_set_image_meta_upon_image_upload' );
function my_set_image_meta_upon_image_upload( $post_ID ) {

    // Check if uploaded file is an image, else do nothing

    if ( wp_attachment_is_image( $post_ID ) ) {
        
       // Get the parent post ID, if there is one

        if( isset($_REQUEST['post_id']) ) {
          $post_id = $_REQUEST['post_id'];
          } else {
          $post_id = false;
          }


            if ($post_id != false) {
        $my_image_title = get_the_title($post_id);
            } else {
        $my_image_title = get_post( $post_ID )->post_title;
            }
        // Sanitize the title:  remove hyphens, underscores & extra spaces:
        $my_image_title = preg_replace( '%\s*[-_\s]+\s*%', ' ',  $my_image_title );

        // Sanitize the title:  capitalize first letter of every word (other letters lower case):
        $my_image_title = ucwords( strtolower( $my_image_title ) );

        // Create an array with the image meta (Title, Caption, Description) to be updated
        // Note:  comment out the Excerpt/Caption or Content/Description lines if not needed
        $my_image_meta = array(
            'ID'        => $post_ID,            // Specify the image (ID) to be updated
            'post_title'    => $my_image_title,     // Set image Title to sanitized title
            'post_excerpt'  => $my_image_title,     // Set image Caption (Excerpt) to sanitized title
            'post_content'  => $my_image_title,     // Set image Description (Content) to sanitized title
        );

        // Set the image Alt-Text
        update_post_meta( $post_ID, '_wp_attachment_image_alt', $my_image_title );

        // Set the image meta (e.g. Title, Excerpt, Content)
        wp_update_post( $my_image_meta );

    } 
}
```

I was try to find a way to take the title from attribute or category name to add it to metas but no luck. If you have any idea i do appreciate it.
I'm not so good to WordPress codex.

Hope this code help.

Comment: This code throws error on other pages such as plugin installation page. Can you modify the code to only run side post area?