# Replace space with hyphen for image filename on upload

Tags: wordpress, image, rename, filenames, auto

I'm using the code bellow (I found it here on stack overflow from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63571688/wordpress-rename-uploaded-images-based-on-the-post-title)) to auto rename image filename and fill alt and title field based on post title.

The good thing is it's working, it's doing its job but problem is with filename : it's using post title with spaces, comas, etc. as filename, which is really not good. It's perfect for filling the title and alt fields but not for a filename.

So, just for the filename, I would like to add something to replace spaces by hyphen (and if possible remove potentials comas or other punctuation)

I thought that the part `add_filter( 'sanitize_file_name', 'file_renamer', 10, 1 );` would to the job, but it's not.

But as I'm really not sure what I'm doing, and as I have poor PHP knowledge, I would be very grateful if you could teach me how to make it work :

```
function file_renamer( $filename ) {
$info = pathinfo( $filename );
$ext  = empty( $info['extension'] ) ? '' : '.' . $info['extension'];
$name = basename( $filename, $ext );


if( $post_id = array_key_exists("post_id", $_POST) ? $_POST["post_id"] : null) {
    if($post = get_post($post_id)) {
        return $post->post_title . $ext;
    }
}

$my_image_title = $post;


$file['name'] = $my_image_title  . - uniqid() . $ext; // uniqid method
// $file['name'] = md5($name) . $ext; // md5 method
// $file['name'] = base64_encode($name) . $ext; // base64 method

return $filename;
}
add_filter( 'sanitize_file_name', 'file_renamer', 10, 1 );

/* Automatically set the image Title, Alt-Text, Caption & Description upon upload */

add_action( 'add_attachment', 'my_set_image_meta_upon_image_upload' );
function my_set_image_meta_upon_image_upload( $post_ID ) {

// Check if uploaded file is an image, else do nothing

if ( wp_attachment_is_image( $post_ID ) ) {
    
   // Get the parent post ID, if there is one

    if( isset($_REQUEST['post_id']) ) {
      $post_id = $_REQUEST['post_id'];
      } else {
      $post_id = false;
      }


        if ($post_id != false) {
    $my_image_title = get_the_title($post_id);
        } else {
    $my_image_title = get_post( $post_ID )->post_title;
        }
    // Sanitize the title:  remove hyphens, underscores & extra spaces:
    $my_image_title = preg_replace( '%\s*[-_\s]+\s*%', ' ',  $my_image_title );

    // Create an array with the image meta (Title, Caption, Description) to be updated
    // Note:  comment out the Excerpt/Caption or Content/Description lines if not needed
    $my_image_meta = array(
        'ID'        => $post_ID,            // Specify the image (ID) to be updated
        'post_title'    => $my_image_title,     // Set image Title to sanitized title
        'post_content'  => $my_image_title,     // Set image Description (Content) to sanitized title
    );

    // Set the image Alt-Text
    update_post_meta( $post_ID, '_wp_attachment_image_alt', $my_image_title );

    // Set the image meta (e.g. Title, Excerpt, Content)
    wp_update_post( $my_image_meta );

} 
}
```

Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 1):

So solution was replacing `post_title` by `post_name` in `file_renamer` function.

Exactly this part : change `return $post->post_title . $ext;` and replace it with `return $post->post_name . $ext;`

And it's working. On upload, this function is renaming the file name with hyphens and filling title, alt text and description fields based on Post Title (without hyphens).