# Rename product image as product title in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, file-upload

i am tryig to rename images in my woocommerce store.
They are uploading in the library with names like 123456.png or main.jpg etc. My goal is to make image name, description and alt text be the same as the product title with a php snippet. I found out that in media library of wordpress there is a field called "Uploaded to" whitch is the post-product that the image attached on and i want to keep the title of this product and set it as title in my image , [as shown here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X3BmE.png). But i dont know how to get the wordpress "Uploaded to" value and use it as a name in images.

After some research i found this question ([Wordpress rename uploaded images based on the post_title](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63571688/wordpress-rename-uploaded-images-based-on-the-post-title)) but the code doesnt worked for me. This is the code that i tryed to use. Also i tryed some plugins and other codes that didnt helped me to find out a solution. Im new in php ,if someone can help i would be glad!

```
function file_renamer( $filename ) {
    $info = pathinfo( $filename );
    $ext  = empty( $info['extension'] ) ? '' : '.' . $info['extension'];
    $name = basename( $filename, $ext );


    if( $post_id = array_key_exists("post_id", $_POST) ? $_POST["post_id"] : null) {
        if($post = get_post($post_id)) {
            return $post->post_title . $ext;
        }
    }
    
    $my_image_title = $post;
    

    $file['name'] = $my_image_title  . - uniqid() . $ext; // uniqid method
    // $file['name'] = md5($name) . $ext; // md5 method
    // $file['name'] = base64_encode($name) . $ext; // base64 method

    return $filename;


  }
add_filter( 'sanitize_file_name', 'file_renamer', 10, 1 );

/* Automatically set the image Title, Alt-Text, Caption & Description upon upload
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
add_action( 'add_attachment', 'my_set_image_meta_upon_image_upload' );
function my_set_image_meta_upon_image_upload( $post_ID ) {

    // Check if uploaded file is an image, else do nothing

    if ( wp_attachment_is_image( $post_ID ) ) {
        
       // Get the parent post ID, if there is one

        if( isset($_REQUEST['post_id']) ) {
          $post_id = $_REQUEST['post_id'];
          } else {
          $post_id = false;
          }


            if ($post_id != false) {
        $my_image_title = get_the_title($post_id);
            } else {
        $my_image_title = get_post( $post_ID )->post_title;
            }
        // Sanitize the title:  remove hyphens, underscores & extra spaces:
        $my_image_title = preg_replace( '%\s*[-_\s]+\s*%', ' ',  $my_image_title );

        // Sanitize the title:  capitalize first letter of every word (other letters lower case):
        $my_image_title = ucwords( strtolower( $my_image_title ) );

        // Create an array with the image meta (Title, Caption, Description) to be updated
        // Note:  comment out the Excerpt/Caption or Content/Description lines if not needed
        $my_image_meta = array(
            'ID'        => $post_ID,            // Specify the image (ID) to be updated
            'post_title'    => $my_image_title,     // Set image Title to sanitized title
            'post_excerpt'  => $my_image_title,     // Set image Caption (Excerpt) to sanitized title
            'post_content'  => $my_image_title,     // Set image Description (Content) to sanitized title
        );

        // Set the image Alt-Text
        update_post_meta( $post_ID, '_wp_attachment_image_alt', $my_image_title );

        // Set the image meta (e.g. Title, Excerpt, Content)
        wp_update_post( $my_image_meta );

    } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found out a solution in MySQL for everyone who maybe need it!

**The title of image :**

```
UPDATE wp_posts AS attachments
JOIN wp_posts AS parent_posts ON attachments.post_parent = parent_posts.ID
SET attachments.post_title = parent_posts.post_title, attachments.guid = REPLACE(attachments.guid, SUBSTRING_INDEX(attachments.guid, '/', -1), parent_posts.post_name)
WHERE attachments.post_type = 'attachment';
```

**The description of image**

```
UPDATE wp_posts AS attachments
JOIN wp_posts AS parent_posts ON attachments.post_parent = parent_posts.ID
SET attachments.post_content = CONCAT(parent_posts.post_title, ' ', parent_posts.post_excerpt)
WHERE attachments.post_type = 'attachment';
```

**Alt text of image**

```
UPDATE wp_postmeta AS alt_text
JOIN wp_posts AS attachments ON alt_text.post_id = attachments.ID
JOIN wp_posts AS parent_posts ON attachments.post_parent = parent_posts.ID
SET alt_text.meta_value = parent_posts.post_title
WHERE attachments.post_type = 'attachment' AND alt_text.meta_key ='_wp_attachment_image_alt';
```