# Wordpress Auto Rename and Fill Attributes on upload to CPT

Tags: php, wordpress, function, add-filter

as you can see this code to rename images by post title works fine.
even with several posts with the same title.

it just puts the numbers: image, image1, image2, image3 .. etc

```
    /*Renaming attachment files to the post title*/
function file_renamer( $filename ) {
    $info = pathinfo( $filename );
    $ext  = empty( $info['extension'] ) ? '' : '.' . $info['extension'];
    $name = basename( $filename, $ext );

    if ( get_post_type( $_REQUEST['post_id'] ) === 'property'){
    if( $post_id = array_key_exists("post_id", $_POST) ? $_POST["post_id"] : null) {
        if($post = get_post($post_id)) {
            return $post->post_title . $ext;
        }
    }
    
    $my_image_title = $post;
    
    $file['name'] = $my_image_title  . - uniqid() . $ext; // uniqid method
    // $file['name'] = md5($name) . $ext; // md5 method
    // $file['name'] = base64_encode($name) . $ext; // base64 method

    return $filename;

  }     
}

add_filter( 'sanitize_file_name', 'file_renamer', 10, 1 );
    
 /* Automatically set the image Title, Alt-Text, Caption & Description upon upload*/
    add_action( 'add_attachment', 'my_set_image_meta_upon_image_upload' );
    function my_set_image_meta_upon_image_upload( $post_ID ) {
    
        // Check if uploaded file is an image, else do nothing
    
        if ( wp_attachment_is_image( $post_ID ) ) {
            
           // Get the parent post ID, if there is one
    
            if( isset($_REQUEST['post_id']) ) {
              $post_id = $_REQUEST['post_id'];
              } else {
              $post_id = false;
              }
    
                if ($post_id != false) {
            $my_image_title = get_the_title($post_id);
                } else {
            $my_image_title = get_post( $post_ID )->post_title;
                }
            
            // Sanitize the title:  remove hyphens, underscores & extra spaces:
            $my_image_title = preg_replace( '%\s*[-_\s]+\s*%', ' ',  $my_image_title );
    
            // Sanitize the title:  capitalize first letter of every word (other letters lower case):
            $my_image_title = ucwords( strtolower( $my_image_title ) );
    
            // Create an array with the image meta (Title, Caption, Description) to be updated
            // Note:  comment out the Excerpt/Caption or Content/Description lines if not needed
            $my_image_meta = array(
                'ID'        => $post_ID,            // Specify the image (ID) to be updated
                'post_title'    => $my_image_title,     // Set image Title to sanitized title
                'post_excerpt'  => $my_image_title,     // Set image Caption (Excerpt) to sanitized title
                'post_content'  => $my_image_title,     // Set image Description (Content) to sanitized title
            );
    
            // Set the image Alt-Text
            update_post_meta( $post_ID, '_wp_attachment_image_alt', $my_image_title );
    
            // Set the image meta (e.g. Title, Excerpt, Content)
            wp_update_post( $my_image_meta );
    
        } 
    }
```

[image]

I believe this code works since **inside** in CPT property he renames my upload to
**post-title.jpg**
result : post-title.jpg , post-title-1.jpg, post-title-2.jpg , post-title-3.jpg, etc....

and **outside** CPT property in wordpress he rename strange **empty-1.jpg** to uploads..
result : -1.jpg , -2.jpg , -3.jpg etc .....

I will need help to add some instructions

I must miss an instruction to tell him ,it should only fire in **CPT property only**

else --> do nothing if there is **no title** and if we are not in CPT property.
so he does not rename the uploads to **'auto-draft.jpg'**  when no title set and image uploaded first .. very annoying.. and if we are outside CPT'property' do nothing = leave the names of the original uploads and ignore this code.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think simply commenting (or removing) these two lines in your `file_renamer()` function will do the trick:

```
$my_image_title = $post;

$file['name'] = $my_image_title  . - uniqid() . $ext; // uniqid method
```

Because `if ( get_post_type( $_REQUEST['post_id'] ) === 'property'){` is the line that checks whether the `post_id` belong to a Custom Post Type. Based on what I understood from your explanation, you only want do the renaming there. If you want to do something else too, you could write inside that IF condition.

So your code would look like this:

```
/*Renaming attachment files to the post title*/
function file_renamer( $filename ) {
    $info = pathinfo( $filename );
    $ext  = empty( $info['extension'] ) ? '' : '.' . $info['extension'];
    $name = basename( $filename, $ext );

    if ( get_post_type( $_REQUEST['post_id'] ) === 'property'){
    if( $post_id = array_key_exists("post_id", $_POST) ? $_POST["post_id"] : null) {
        if($post = get_post($post_id)) {
            return $post->post_title . $ext;
        }
    }
    
    //$my_image_title = $post;
    
    //$file['name'] = $my_image_title  . - uniqid() . $ext; // uniqid method
    // $file['name'] = md5($name) . $ext; // md5 method
    // $file['name'] = base64_encode($name) . $ext; // base64 method

    return $filename;

  }     
}
```

Btw, I didn't tested the code!

Comment: thank you Akhilesh for your message,
i just tested, i still have the same problem, i updated the post so you can see the errors i have